# Using different Miniconda installs to create and activate Conda environments

Tags: python, conda

Are there any issues with creating a Conda environment using Miniconda, then activating it via a separate install of Miniconda? For example, if I create an environment in Miniconda2, but activate with Miniconda3, will that yield problems? My intuition is that an OS-agnostic environment platform should also be install-agnostic, but I have my doubts.

Comment: Why do you want to have multiple Minicondas installed? Even if it works (which I doubt) it sounds like a mess.

Comment: We are using a distribution mechanism to deploy a conda environment from a master to its slaves. One install is used to create the environment on the master, and another is used to activate the environment on the slaves. Given that the master and slaves are on different machines, I'm not sure how it would be possible to use a single install

Comment: @Zach How are you replicating/cloning the environments?

Comment: One thing I would be worried about are environments that use newer features, like defining environment-specific environment variables (`conda env config vars`). Older versions of Conda will likely fail to handle them. If you match the Conda versions across the machines, then I don't see a problem.

Comment: @AMC, we are using CVMFS, a read-only filesystem, to distribute the environments.

Comment: @merv That's a good point. Given that, I think the two options are:
1) keep the Miniconda versions in sync between master and slaves; 2) deploy the Miniconda install on the master using the same distribution mechanism as the conda environments, which would ensure 100% consistency between master & slaves

Comment: @Zach _we are using CVMFS, a read-only filesystem, to distribute the environments._ How does that work? The machines have Miniconda installed, and then have access to the environment folder on the master? _deploy the Miniconda install on the master using the same distribution mechanism as the conda environments, which would ensure 100% consistency between master & slaves_ If that works relatively easily, without any weird issues, it sounds like a good solution.